# Just when are lambda captures initialized?

Tags: c++, lambda

In the following function, can I rely on the captured variable 'order' to be up to date, i.e.

1. Will the function always work as expected?
2. Is there a difference between capturing by value or reference.
3. Is the function reentrant?

```js
struct Entry
{
    std::string name;
    double earnings;
};

enum Column { Name, Earnings };
enum SortOrder { Ascending, Descending };

void sortByColumn(std::vector<Entry>& entries, Column column, SortOrder order)
{
    std::function<bool(const Entry&, const Entry&)> comparators[] =
    {
        [&](const Entry& a, const Entry& b) { return order==Ascending ?
            a.name < b.name : a.name > b.name;  },
        [=](const Entry& a, const Entry& b) { return order==Ascending ?
            a.earnings < b.earnings : a.earnings > b.earnings;  }
    };
    std::sort(entries.begin(), entries.end(), comparators[column]);
}
```

You can find a full example here: http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/240b74d1706a1b6f

Comment: Possible duplicate of [In C++11, when are a lambda expression's bound variables supposed to be captured-by-value?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7881149/in-c11-when-are-a-lambda-expressions-bound-variables-supposed-to-be-captured)

Comment: @JamesElderfield I would argue that this is not a dupe to the linked question, as it asks about MSVC behavior. The answers are pertinent, but the question itself is not a dupe.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The thing that you must recognize is that a lambda is a closure type object:

> The lambda expression is a prvalue expression an unnamed temporary object of unique unnamed non-union non-aggregate class type, known as closure type, which is declared (for the purposes of Argument-Dependent Lookup) in the smallest block scope, class scope, or namespace scope that contains the lambda expression<sup>[[source](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/lambda#Explanation)]</sup>

You can think of the lambda's capture list as constructor arguments. In this case you passed `order` by value/reference into the 1<sup>st</sup>/2<sup>nd</sup> `comparators` respectively. **Since `order` does not change over the lifetime of `comparators`, passing by reference or value will have identical results in your example.**

But if this function were called with `order` set to `Ascending` and you added this to the bottom of `sortByColumn`:

```
order = Descending;
std::sort(entries.begin(), entries.end(), comparators[0]);
```

You would have sorted `entries` by `name` in **descending** order. Meaning the change to `order` effected the lambda.

If you'd done this however, and `sortByColumn` was again passed `order` as `Ascending`:

```
order = Descending;
std::sort(entries.begin(), entries.end(), comparators[1]);
```

You would have sorted `entries` by `earnings` in **ascending** order. Meaning the change to `order` did not effect the lambda.

---

When deciding whether to capture by reference the same considerations should be applied that you use in deciding whether or not to use a reference or copy as an object member:

1. You must use a reference if the object cannot be copy constructed, and you might *choose* to use a reference if copy construction is expensive
2. You must make a copy if the lifetime of the lambda is going to exceed the lifetime of what it's capturing, and you might *choose* to use make a copy if you are providing the lambda to be used externally to your code

Answer (score 2):

1. The code works as expected.
2. There is a difference, of course. Although it doesn't change the end result in this example, I would prefer capture by value. The reason is that it's just base types you're capturing and there are no write operations in the lambda. Also, it's good style to always capture explicitly:

```
    std::function<bool(const Entry&, const Entry&)> comparators[] =
    {
        [order](const Entry& a, const Entry& b) { return order==Ascending ? a.name < b.name : a.name > b.name;  },
        [order](const Entry& a, const Entry& b) { return order==Ascending ? a.earnings < b.earnings : a.earnings > b.earnings;  }
    };
```

3. `sortByColumn` is reentrant. It has no state and no side effects besides changing `entries`.

If you care about performance, it's a good idea to check the sort `order` outside the lambdas and pass the lambda directly to `std::sort`, rather than putting it into a `std::function` first. You'd need four different lambdas tough.